# How to impose default style on styles with Control Template in WPF

Tags: wpf, styles, controltemplate

In my case, based on configuration settings grid lines should appear in different colors.

I have defined a simple style with TargetType of `CellValuePresenter` and I noticed that the style is applied to all columns except the ones which also have a style with target type of `CellValuePresenter` and have their own `ControlTemplate`. And I have lots of styles with `ControlTemplate`s for `CellValuePresenter` across the solution, and it is not possible to change all of them to be `BasedOn` this new style I created.

What are my options so that the styles with `ControlTemplate`s pickup my changes without modifying each one of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Un)fortunately, styles don't apply like they do in CSS, so there's no ambiguity of what you will end up with at the end, where styles build up on each other.

If you create a style for a type, it is applied across all types in the scope of your style.  This means if you include it at the top in your app.xaml, everything is affected, but if you include it only for a user control or window.xaml, it only applies to that.

If you create a style and apply it on a specific control, the local style set will override the global type based one.  Unless you use BasedOn, which you specifically say you cannot do.

Unfortunately, I think you will be forced to refactor how you handle your styles to get the look you are trying to achieve, and `BasedOn` will be the way to go.

Answer (score 2):

You can make a style `BasedOn` the default style for that element so that it includes all setters from the implicit style as well.

For example,

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type CellValuePresenter}">
    <!-- Generic Style Setters -->
</Style>

<!-- This Style will include the setters from the implicit style above -->
<Style x:Key="CustomCellStyle"
       TargetType="{x:Type CellValuePresenter}"
       BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type CellValuePresenter}}">

    <Setter Property="ControlTemplate" ... />

</Style>
```

Comment: I cannot use BasedOn property as I have too many styles with ControlTemplate and any future styles are also not enforced by default.

Comment: @SujithJagini You could try placing your implicit base style in `<Application.Resources>`, as those styles will usually apply application-wide regardless of template boundaries, unlike styles in `<Window.Resources>` or other `.Resources`. I'm not positive if that will work though for your setters, as I've only tested that with a few common style setters such as font color.